# Why my window not showing full content if height is smaller?

Tags: html, css

On my page I have created popup window with defined height of 800px. It looks properly but whenever my window change height to smaller size for example 600px then it hide top content even if scrollbar is in very top.

Window with 800px looks like:

[image: 800px Height]

Window with 600px looks like:

[image: 600px Height]

This is css code I have now:

```
.schedule { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color: #fff; overflow: auto; }
.schedule .day { width: 100%; height: auto; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); backdrop-filter: blur(10px); display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.schedule .name { background: rgba(255,156,0,0.3); padding: 10px 0; text-align: center; }
.schedule .item { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; padding: 10px 0; }
.schedule .item span:nth-child(1) { color: #ff9c00; font-weight: 600; }
.schedule .item span:nth-child(2) { color: #fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 300; }
```

And this is what comes from php:

```
<div class="schedule">
    <div class="day">
        <div class="name">Poniedziałek</div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color:">
            <span>Anna</span>
            <span>Spacer w chmurach</span>
            <span>Od: <b>17:12</b> Do: <b>19:12</b></span>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color:">
            <span>Marcin</span>
            <span>Kuferek z muzyką</span>
            <span>Od: <b>20:00</b> Do: <b>22:00</b></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">
        <div class="name">Wtorek</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">
        <div class="name">Środa</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">
        <div class="name">Czwartek</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">
        <div class="name">Piątek</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">
        <div class="name">Sobota</div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color:">
            <span>Monika</span>
            <span>test</span>
            <span>Od: <b>12:25</b> Do: <b>15:25</b></span>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color:">
            <span>Maciek</span>
            <span>test</span>
            <span>Od: <b>17:20</b> Do: <b>20:20</b></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="day">
        <div class="name">Niedziela</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What could I possible do wrong? Does problem comes with browser am using? (Opera GX)

Comment: Looks like height is `100%` and not `800px`?

Comment: Yes set `schedule` to `800px` or auto... otherwise if you want a fixed height container use `overflow: scroll`

Comment: Try `height: auto;`, `height: 800px;` or `min-height: 100%;`

Comment: Setting `schedule` to `auto`, `800px` or `min-height: 100%;` doesn't fix the problem. Also `overflow: scroll` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Problem found!!! my `body` height has been set to `100%`. Removing it fix problem but main website is using same stylesheet, and objects are not showing as it was. Is there different way to fix it?